# Creating a config list of classpath jars in ant

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I have a list of jars in an ant task like this..

```
  <path id="lib.path.id">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
      <include name="jar/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
```

I want to unroll this into a config file like this..

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/activation.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/bcel.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../lib/c3p0-0.8.4.5.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=../lib/cglib-full-2.0.2.jar
....
```

How can I do this in ant?

Comment: If you want to use the *Tanuki Service Wrapper for Java*, you are not forced to list all your `jar` in the `wrapper.conf`, you can simply indicate `wrapper.java.classpath.1=/path/to/lib/*.jar`.

Comment: But it's just a guess, that's why it's a comment ;)

Comment: @romaintaz Thanks that is a useful tip, I might be able to do that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in my comment, if you are using [Tanuki Service Wrapper for Java](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/), you are not forced to list all your jar in the `wrapper.conf`, you can simply indicate a path that contains all your JAR files:

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=/path/to/lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=/any/other/lib/directory/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=/a/path/to/one/library/my-library.jar
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ant you can use the [pathconvert task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) in order to convert the path collection to a String. Then you can use it in your config file. It won't be in the exact format you specified, but it will be in a proper classpath format, ready to use for a java command.

```
<pathconvert targetos="unix" property="wrapper.java.classpath" refid="lib.path.id"/>
```

To create a properties file use the [propertyfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) task:

```
<propertyfile file="my.properties">
  <entry  key="wrapper.java.classpath" value="${wrapper.java.classpath}"/>
</propertyfile>
```

Comment: Not really what I was asking for.  I need the format as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

Eran hinted the right direction. I am using the ant.library.dir as an example.

```
<project name="util">

<property name="lib.dir" value="${ant.library.dir}"/>

<target name="gen-property-file" description="">

    <path id="lib.path.id">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}wrapper.java.classpath.Number="             
        property="echo.path.compile"             
        refid="lib.path.id">
    </pathconvert>

    <echo file="my.properties">wrapper.java.classpath.Number=${echo.path.compile}</echo>

</target>
```

This snippet procudes an file my.properties:

```
wrapper.java.classpath.Number=D:\Programme\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-antlr.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.Number=D:\Programme\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-apache-bcel.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.Number=D:\Programme\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-apache-bsf.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.Number=D:\Programme\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-apache-log4j.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.Number=D:\Programme\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-apache-oro.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.Number=D:\Programme\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-apache-regexp.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.Number=D:\Programme\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32
```

...

You can replace the .Number and the Basepath manually or with a script.